# How to upload a file from my session into azure datastorage?

Tags: pandas, azure, azure-devops, data-storage

I dowload a datafile from my azure datastorage, preprocess it and again want to upload the processed file to the datastore as a final csv, how do I do it? I tried the appraoch below but it is giving me a directory error:

```
datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
datastore_paths_train = [(datastore, 'X.csv')]
traindata = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path=datastore_paths_train)
train = traindata.to_pandas_dataframe()


#preprocessing the data 
X, y = preprocess_data(train)


#splitting the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

#uploading data to datastore
print('Uploading data to datastore')
outputs_folder = './Scaling_data'
os.makedirs(outputs_folder, exist_ok=True)
datastore.upload(X_train, outputs_folder)
```

How do I get my 'X_train' a directory, I tried making it a Path object but that also didn't work. I might be wrong here, if there are any other ways to upload a csv to datastore I would be happy to learn.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer, how did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below `datastore.upload` method shows you need to specify the source files directory to upload. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.azure_storage_datastore.azureblobdatastore?view=azure-ml-py#upload-src-dir--target-path-none--overwrite-false--show-progress-true-) for more details.

`upload(src_dir, target_path=None, overwrite=False, show_progress=True)`

So you need to save dataframe `X_train` to a local file first. See below example:

```
outputs_folder = "./Scaling_data"

# create local directory if not exist
if not os.path.exists(outputs_folder):
    os.mkdir(outputs_folder)

local_path = './Scaling_data/prepared.csv'

# save dataframe X_train to local file './Scaling_data/prepared.csv'
X_train.to_csv(local_path)

# upload the local file from src_dir to the target_path in datastore
datastore.upload(src_dir=outputs_folder, target_path=outputs_folder)
```

You can also check out [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-datasets#create-a-tabulardataset).